# How to find subscripts of matching element(s) in matlab/octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Given a value in a matrix how can you get the subscript(s) at which the value occurs in the matrix?

So in this example

```
octave:27> X=rand(3)
X =

   0.46749   0.41187   0.26832
   0.91106   0.63567   0.97302
   0.71809   0.55269   0.84742
```

Given the value 0.26832  I would like to extract the subscript (1,3)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
[ix,iy]=find(X==0.26832)
ix = 
    1
iy = 
    3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[i j]=ind2sub(size(X),find(X==0.26832))
```

Comment: weird, I get ix = [](0x1)   and   iy = [](0x1), using octave 3.2.4

Comment: It is because no element is "exactly" equal to 0.26832. You can try the followin code: X=[1 2 3; 4 5 6]; [i j]=ind2sub(size(X),find(X==5))

Comment: right, that makes sense, thanks. I was somewhat dubious about doing a fp comparison without using some epsilon.

Comment: What is the advantage of this combination of `find`, `size` and `ind2sub` when `find` alone can produce the same output?

Comment: You're right, your solution is better. I upvote it. I always get confused with the output of "find" when there are multiple ouputs.